# WPF MVVM. Не обновляется вычисляемое свойство в DataGrid при изменение свойства

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть WPF MVVM приложение, используется Caliburn.Micro.

Есть Model:

```
public class StatisticItem : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public StatisticItem()
    {

    }

    private string _balanceValue = "";

    public string BalanceView { get => CommonModel.CalculateValue(BalanceValue); }
    public string BalanceValue { get => _balanceValue; set { _balanceValue = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => BalanceValue); NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => BalanceView); } }
}
```

Есть View:

```
<DataGrid Name="StatisticItems" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=StatisticItems}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Balance" Width="150">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BalanceView}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=BalanceValue}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

И простая ViewModel:

```
public class StatisticViewModel
{
    public StatisticViewModel()
    {
        StatisticItems = new BindableCollection<StatisticItem>();
    }

    private BindableCollection<StatisticItem> _statisticItems = null;

    public BindableCollection<StatisticItem> StatisticItems { get => _statisticItems; set => _statisticItems = value; }
}
```

BalanceView отображает простые математические операции от BalanceValue.

Когда в режиме редактирования изменяем значение BalanceValue и после переходим на следующую ячейку в DataGrid этой же строки, обновление BalanceView НЕ срабатывает. BalanceView такое же какое было до изменения.

Когда же после редактирования сразу переходим в любую ячейку любой другой строки DataGrid значение BalanceView обновляется сразу.

Почему так происходит, и как исправить?

Comment: Не `обновляется` зависимое `readonly` (!) свойство

Comment: Согласен, написал не совсем понятно первоначально, подкорректировал!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените вот так:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=BalanceValue,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
```

P.s. На будущее, выкладывая код освобождайте его от незначительных подробностей, типа ScreenTabItem, чтобы его можно было сразу брать и использовать. Сейчас приходится чистить, чтобы проверить как работает.

Comment: Действительно работает. Я ранее пробовал добавить UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, но он почему не работал. А сейчас работает. Чудеса! Спасибо!